re.sub eats next charater when replacing with more
so i was trying to format my text for markdown v2, basically I just want to replace a special character a with \a
when trying to do this with regex, it does so< but the new symbol eats up the next one
example:
import re
string = 'delivery - options (1 of 3)'
markdown_pattern = re.compile("(?P<markdown>[\'*-_{}\[\]<>\(\)#+-.!]).")
result = markdown_pattern.sub(r'\\\g<markdown>', string)
print(result)
print(len(string))
print(len(result))

what i get in the end is
delivery \-options \( of \3

instead of
delivery \- options \(1 of 3\)
result and string are the same length
i've seen re.sub make strings shorter, thought it can elongate them

This version is working:
inp = 'delivery - options (1 of 3)'
output = re.sub(r'([\'*_{}\[\]<>()#+.!-])', r'\\\1', inp)
print(output)

# delivery \- options \(1 of 3\)

I have made the following changes:

I am phrasing the regex search as searching for just one special character and capturing it in \1.  Your original pattern also had a trailing dot after the special character, meaning that every match would consume/eat an additional following character.
Your regex pattern erroneously had a dash - in the middle of the character class.  This had the unintended effect of including all character between * and _, which also included numbers.  I moved the dash to the end of the character class to avoid this.


+-. includes ,

You can use a lookahead and place the dash at the end of character class:

import re
string = 'delivery - options (1 of 3)'
result = re.sub(r"(?=['*_{}\[\]<>()#+.!-])", r"\\", string)
print(result)

Results:
delivery \- options \(1 of 3\)


Note that - is a metachar.


Note that - is not a regex metacharacter...but is has a special meaning inside a regex character class.

@TimBiegeleisen Isn't your above comment literally the definition of a metacharacter within the character class?
